# Content pulled from JSON becomes ASCII encoded when special character

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, json, gtl

I am successfully pulling content from a JSON feed into an email using

`set @json = TreatAsContent(HttpGET("https://test.com/fakeaddress"))`

The feed contains a lot of special characters (åäöé) and such
and the feed itself is displaying these properly.

However, in my email, all content gets strangely encoded, like for example

> Ã„Ã¤rimmÃ¤

The email of course has

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

I am using TreatAsContent to define all different parts from the json, like:

```
set @title_x = TreatAsContent("{{title}}")
```

How can I make sure the content is displayed properly in utf-8?

Comment: What Target Language you have selected in email?

Comment: @PalashRai, Unicode as always, and it has always worked fine...except for now when I'm working with the feed.

Comment: Can you confirm that you selected UTF-8 as the target language in the email properties and not just defined it as the charset attribute?

Comment: Yep, target language is of course utf-8.
Also, I can use special characters in the rest of the email body. It is just the parts pulled from the json feed that end up wrong.